# IOS: App rejected because of App Tracking Transparency on WebView

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, privacy-policy, apptrackingtransparency

I'm working on an app made in React Native with Expo.

It uses a web view to show the site in the app.

Everything worked well, but when I submitted my app to the App Store, it got rejected.

The mail said:

> We noticed you collect data to track after the user selects "Ask App
> Not to Track" on the App Tracking Transparency permission request.
>
> Specifically, we noticed your app accesses web content you own and
> collects cookies for tracking after the user asked you not to track
> them.

After that, using the [expo tracking transparency library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/tracking-transparency/), I added a permission request to track data.

If the user doesn't accept it, I disable `third party cookies` on the web view.

After submitting again to the App Store, **I got the exact same message**.

I don't know what to do, because I can't control the site, and I'm limited to the [React Native web view props](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md)

Maybe, **I could enable incognito mode** if the user doesn't want the app to track, but I'm not sure if this will be accepted too.

Comment: that's interesting to see that Apple now enforces web view cookies, do you mind me asking what you mean by "can't control the site" as Apple seems to assume the site you're using in the webview is yours?

Comment: @Simon What I mean is that I can't modify the way the website uses the cookies directly from the app.

Comment: I have been dealing with issues related to the ATT request for a month, I have been refused a dozen updates. If they find you a problem like this, start a conversation on the page where they rejected the app and explain to them why they should accept it or what they want you to do. You can also put, after the user has declared "no" in the ATT request, a page where you say that the user accepts the use of some cookies for web viewing, for example, asking the user to confirm.

Comment: idk at this stage it sounds odd, have you explained that the only cookies used are technical cookies (if that's actually true)? In that sense I agree with @FreeLearning, engage them in a conversation why you're following the ATT. Maybe that way they'll tell you more. The problem with setting cookies after: Apple requires you to follow the ATT decisions, no matter what.   P.S. Do let us know how it developed.

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to publish you app with only the technical cookies enabled when user does not allow tracking? I am in the same situation and I would like to know how they handled your case

Comment: @giani.sim We wrote 5 different mails to apple and still haven't got an answer !

Comment: It is very unclear how should the webview tracking be managed. I can't find a clear answer into the App Transparency docs :( At the moment I will let the user use the app just if tracking is allowed. Otherwise I will redirect the user to the application settings

Comment: @johannb75 were u able to solve it. We are in the same crisis

Comment: @giani.sim, how did the app go? did it get accepted?

Comment: Yes, it was accepted without any problems. I just added the App Transparency Framework dialog and let the user interact with the webview whatever choice was made

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue i solved it like this:
change the privacy of the app on apple store, go to app privacy and in data types section click edit and select Identifiers (Device ID) and set this one as used for tracking purposes. and make sure that this is the only one selected as used for tracking.

also make sure that the permission is showing on real device (so test it first on TestFlight).

another thing is you need to tell them where you show this permission send them video to tell them where you show the permission.